# How to make a child theme in WordPress

Tags: html, wordpress

I'm trying to create a child theme in WordPress and I'm following these steps:

1. Copy folder you are interested in
2. Rename folder to `namechildtheme`
3. Delete every file in the folder except:

   - style.css
   - function.php
   - screenshot.png
4. Open file style.css and modify the first block

   - Theme Name: new child theme
   - Theme URI: http://sitename.it
   - Author: Mauro Rossi
   - Author URI: http://sitename.it
   - Description: Tema new theme
   - Version: 1.0.0
   - Template: new father name
   - License: GNU General Public License v2 or later
   - License URI: http://www.gu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html
   - Tags: key word site
   - Text Domain: name-theme-child
5. Delete all the code under this:
   `@import url ("/father-name-theme/style.css")`

Is there something wrong?

Comment: Are you getting any errors, are those steps not working? what is happening?

Comment: no unfortunatelly even if I follow these steps, childtheme not appers.

Answer (score 1):

Template should not be 'new father' - it should be the name of the existing theme that will be the parent of this child. 
EG: Template:     twentyfifteen

or in your case, perhaps?

Template:   father-name-theme

Comment: father theme is what I meant as the name of the existing theme, the theme that I used was laveo.